# Azure Search - Translate a full document with split skill

Tags: azure, postman, azure-cognitive-search

I would like to share with you a question in order to translate a document calling the split skill of Microsoft as its input. I am calling the API through POSTMAN creating the next skill:

```
{
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.SplitSkill",
    "textSplitMode" : "pages", 
    "maximumPageLength": 50000,
    "inputs": [
    {
        "name": "text",
        "source": "/document/content"
    },
    { 
        "name": "languageCode",
        "source": "/document/languageCode"
    }
    ],
    "outputs": [
    {
         "name": "textItems",
         "targetName": "pages"
    }
    ]
}
```

Once the split is done, ideally I would use "pages" as the input for my translate function in Azure as follows:

```
    {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Custom.WebApiSkill",
    "description": "Our new translator custom skill",
    "uri": "https://translate-function.azurewebsites.net//api/Translate?code=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "batchSize":1,
    "context": "/document/pages/*",
    "inputs" : [
        {
            "name":"text",
            "source": "/document/pages/*"
        }
    ],
    "outputs": [
        {
            "name":"text",
            "targetName":"englishText"
        }
    ]
    }
```

Some of you can see what is going wrong? The result englishText is empty in the Solution explorer.

I have ensured that the translate function works properly in PSOTMAN!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your skillset looks good. Can you validate that your translate function works with a sample payload like this …

```
{"values":[{"recordId":"0","data":{"text":"your text goes here"}}]}
```

Comment: It works properly with a short text. The problem comes when the text exceeds the limit of characters that the API translate of Azure allows and therefore it returns a [].

Comment: The easiest way to validate would be to look t the "enriched" field https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-concept-troubleshooting#tip-4-looking-at-enriched-documents-under-the-hood

Comment: Also consider logging/remote debugging your custom skill code to see what's happening when the text is large. You will need to set the split skill maximumPageLength to a smaller value depending on the max length the translate API accepts